How to say "to settle for" in japanese?
How can I say "to settle for" in japanese? I've been having this question for so long because I wanted to translate this sentence: "I wish I could settle for this"
Thank you very much beforehand<33

Perhaps 認{みと}める (Wiktionary, Jisho).

Could you provide a context or situation? Sounds that there are a lot of possible options.

The word "settle" has many meanings in English. Which one do you mean ? Like a court settlement "I'd settle for 5 million dollars" or like you're good for something "I'd settle for Seattle, no need for New York. (Seattle is good enough)"

@broccoliforest i want to convey the feeling of conforming with the way a situation is even though its not good enough compared to what it was or what it could be. "I wish I could settle for this" is like, Id really want to settle with the way things are now because I would be much happier not chasing an unrealistic future. Thank you so much for your interest!!

@dvx2718 please take a look at my response to broccoliforest, there I explain what I mean :)

@mariomariomario No need for anything complicated, a simple XXでいいです or XXで十分です would suffice to express the meaning

If you mean that you accept that something is good enough, if not the best, you can say ○○で妥協する.

金が無いから中古品で妥協する

妥協する can imply negotiation and compromise with someone else. So the reverse translation might not work depending on the context.
○○で我慢する is another phrase that you can use. This usually implies a tough and temporary situation. So if want to say you decide that you are happy with something indefinitely, there might be a slight gap. (Not a huge one, I would say, though.)

I will give you an example so you can understand me better: My headphones have fallen to the water and I inicially thought they wouldnt work, then suddently one side is working so its not as bad as you imagined, but deeply you miss when both sides worked. "I wish I could settle for this instead of obsessing with the past" thank you!

@mariomariomario, from your example, it sounds like what you really want to say is more like "I wish I could be satisfied with this," which is similar to "I wish I could settle for this" but has a slightly different nuance in English. (If you are continuing to use the headphones, then you are in fact settling for them, whether you are "obsessing [over] the  past" while doing so or not.)

@Nanigashi yess I guess that is a great way of putting it, it expresses the situation I was talking about :)
